# Need help on deleting a row from database with a button

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask, cs50

I need help with my CS50 webapp final project, I'm having trouble deleting a row from a SQLite (phpLiteAdmin) table with a button.

[here's how it looks like but the buttons won't work][image: 1]

here is the table code in index.html:

```
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Word</th>
                        <th>Translation</th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for word in words %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ word.kelime }}</td>
                            <td>{{ word.ceviri }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="delete({{ word.id }})" type="delete">Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and here is what i did in application.py:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
  if request.method == "POST":

    kelime = request.form.get("kelime")
    ceviri = request.form.get("ceviri")

    db.execute("INSERT INTO words (kelime, ceviri) VALUES (?,?)", kelime, ceviri)

    return redirect("/")

  else:

    words = db.execute("SELECT * FROM words")
    return render_template("index.html", words=words)

def delete(id):
  if request.method == "POST":
    db.execute("DELETE FROM words WHERE id = ?", id)
    return redirect("/")
```

I don't know what I did wrong, I'm new to coding so it would be great if you guys could dumb it down for me. Thank you in advance

Comment: paste your code as text instead of screenshot

Comment: Your button is trying to call a Javascript function called `delete`.  Do you have such a function that creates a POST request into your application?  I'm guessing that's the root of the problem -- you expected the button to call your Python code.  If you do have a `delete` function, please post it.

Comment: You do not really want to insert two new words every time you redirect back to the index.  The insert option should be a separate request.  Otherwise, as soon as you delete, the browser will redirect back to index and you'll re-insert.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
 <td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="delete({{ word.id }})" type="delete">Delete</button>
 </td>
```

Try this:

```
  <td>
    <form method='POST' action='delete'>
      <input type=hidden name='id' value='{{ word.id }}'>
      <button class='btn btn-primary' type='delete'>Delete</button>
    </form>
  </td>
```